# VBScript unable to iterate XML nodes

Tags: xml, vbscript

This is the snippet of my code, this part is to read the XML file and get the last child attribute of Operations. In this case, I want to get the type C. The thing is the script skipped the entire `For` loop, as proven from the echo I put. I did some searching and I still couldn't find out what's wrong with my code.

```vb
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
counter = 0
xmlDoc.Load(mostrecent(i).Name)

Set colNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Runs/Run/Operations")

WScript.Echo counter      '<--appears
For Each objNode In colNodes
    WScript.Echo counter  '<--didn't appear

    If Attr.Exists(objNode.LastChild.GetAttribute("type")) Then
        counter = counter + 1
        WScript.Echo counter
    End If
Next
```

XML:

```xml
<Runs>
 <Run>
  <Operations>
   <Operation type="A"></Operation>
   <Operation type="B"></Operation>
   <Operation type="C"></Operation>
  </Operations>
 </Run>
</Runs>
```

Comment: Attr is a Dictionary object, if the attribute value is one of the value inside Dictionary, counter +1.

Comment: If you don't see any output from the loop at all that means `SelectNodes` doesn't return any nodes. This usually happens when XML data has namespaces. Does your actual XML contain `xmlns=...` attributes and/or `<foo:bar ...>` nodes?

Comment: No, my XML starts and ends with <Runs>

Comment: Then the code should display the value of `counter` at least twice. Please update your question with a [mcve] so that we can actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code to get the `type` attribute of the last child of the parent-node `Operations`

```vb
Dim objXML, strPath, objCol
strPath = mostrecent(i).Name
Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async=False
objXML.load strPath
strQuery = "/Runs/Run/Operations/Operation"
Set objCol = objXML.selectNodes(strQuery)         'collection of all the <Operation> nodes
MsgBox objCol.item(objCol.length-1).attributes.getnameditem("type").text
```

Update:
Works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: BTW You can add `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` in front of your code snippet to fix the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for the Suggestion. Updated.

Comment: @Gurman yes, I got what I wanted, thank you for your quick response, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get all Operations with Type=C, you can use the below code

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
With objXML
    .SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    .ValidateOnParse = True
    .Async = False
    .Load "C:\Users\Pankrit\Desktop\test.xml"
End With

Set nodesC = objXML.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Runs/Run/Operations/Operation[@type='C']")
If nodesC.Length >= 1 Then
    For Each nodeC In nodesC
        MsgBox nodeC.NodeName
    Next
End If
```